# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException when running tests using jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, jenkins, test-explorer

I have windows 10 workstation and I have installed MS visual studio latest professional edition on it. 
I am using WinAppDriver v1.2.
I have selenium tests written that I run using testexplorer/command line/Jenkins. Running through MS VS Test explorer and cmd line works. But the same command executed from Jenkins windows shell throws error.

**cmd used:** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:\tests\project-test\bin\Release\Test.dll"  /ResultsDirectory:"C:\tests\"\ /Logger:txt

**Error:**
" OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to locate opened application window with appId:".

Any idea how to reolve this issue?